# How to generate the appsettings.<EnvironmentName>.json file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 2 WebAPI which will be deployed across the following environments:

INT, QA, STAGE, PRODUCTION environments.

Based on the above, I need to have `appsettings.<EnvironmentName>.json` file for each environment. From the link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1, I see that

In case of local development environment, the Environment Variable called ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is set to Development. In case of the deployment where ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is not set, the default is Production

I would like to know what are the steps required to take care while preparing the `appsettings.<EnvironmentName>.json` file for INT, QA and STAGE environment. Do I need to set the environment explicitly for each environment web server:

set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development.

Can anyone help me to by providing their guidance?

Answer (score 27):

I might be missing something, but this seems pretty straight-forward. To create the environment-specific setting files, you literally just create them in your project, i.e. create a new file called `appsettings.Foo.json` in the root of your project. Visual Studio will automatically put it under `appsettings.json` as a parent in the Solution Explorer.

On the server, yes, you'd need to set the environment you want to run under to `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`. If it's supposed to use `appsettings.QA.json`, then set it to `QA`. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Is there some trick to this? Simply making the file does not automatically nest it under the parent file.

Comment: It may not nest in the UI, but that has nothing to do with whether or not it will work.

Comment: What worked for me was to use "copy-paste" on the appsettings.json file and then rename it.  Hitting enter on the rename causes it to nest

Comment: I ran into an issue where I copy and pasted the development file and it would not auto-nest under appsettings.json. I eventually realized I had a space in the filename after "appsettings" that was hard to see. As soon as I removed that space it did its thing.

Comment: To check the `Environment`  in code, `IWebHostEnvironment env` `env.IsEnvironment("QA");` can be used.

Answer (score 5):

1. Right clicked on Project
2. Add new item
3. search for json
4. Choose Application Configuration file
5. Name your new setting file
6. It will automatically added under appsetting.json

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will have to set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` on the server with the configuration you wish to host the app.

Take a look at the sample project provided by Microsoft on Github

[Sample Environment project](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/environments/sample/EnvironmentsSample)

Comment: **USE THIS LINK** Samples moved [here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/environments).

Answer (score 2):

First, in Visual Studio you will have to right click your project name and add a new item.

Inside 'Add new Item' window chose 'Scripts' on the left column, and look for JavaScript JSON Configuration File template.

Name it as `appsettings.Production.json`, for example, and click 'Add'.
It's going to connect automatically to `appsettings.json`.

To set which environment your application runs on, just set up the
`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable.

Set the variable through the command prompt by typing set
`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production` in Windows or export
`ASPNET_CORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production` in Linux.