# Override appsettings.json on Azure using ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have an ASP Core 2.2 application which runs fine.

- I have an appsettings.json
- I have an appsettings.QA.json
- I have an Azure App Service which I have added ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable to in the Configuration > App Settings section of the portal and set the value to "QA".
- I have also added a connection string directly to the Configuration > Connection Strings section of the portal.

When I publish to my Azure App Service, I want to override the settings in appsettings.json with values from appsettings.QA.json. I am struggling to make sense of how this should be configured.

I am reading out the values from the appsettings via the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration implementation which is injected into classes where I need such configuration.

So far I have the following:

Program.cs:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            config.SetBasePath(hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

When the app runs in Azure, it is picking up the connection string from the portal and using it. However, when I read out a value from the appsettings, I always get the value from appsettings.json not appsettings.QA.json.

1. Can anyone point out how to configure the transforms correctly for an ASP Core 2.2 application?
2. Am I going about this in the wrong way entirely?

**Update**

- I have removed my custom code above as suggested as it is not needed.
- If I output `@Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")` in my view, I get: "QA;Development". It seems that the "Development" is coming from the web.config which also has ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT set.

Comment: “However, when I read out a value from the appsettings” – How are you doing that exactly? Can you show how you consume the configuration?

Comment: Just to rule out the simplest of possibilities - Have you confirmed that `appsettings.QA.json` exists in the App Service? If it's easy enough, it might be worth changing to `optional: false` just to make sure the file is being picked up.  Also, the `ConfigureAppConfiguration` isn't really needed in your example, as this is the default setup when using `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`. Lastly, as @poke asks, how exactly do you read this configuration value?

Comment: @KirkLarkin The appsettings.QA.json is definitely published to the Azure App Service. I am reading out the values via the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration implementation which is injected into the classes I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have this working correctly:

- Removed the custom code from the Program.cs as suggested by @KirkLarkin and @dee-zg.
- Removed the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT setting from the Azure portal. The reason for this is that there is also a web.config in the app which has this setting. When reading from the config, it seems that this version is used, not the Azure portal version.

Why is the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in the web.config? There is a discussion about this [here](https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/issues/564). Ultimately, what I have done to work around this is to add transforms for the web.config.

Answer (score 4):

you shouldn’t read environment from `appsettings`. environment is set on machine level and is read at startup.

you have 2 options:

1. for local machine, set environment variable in `launch.settings`
2. in azure, set it in app service configuration as environment variable

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: _“you shouldn’t read environment from appsettings”_ – What do you mean with that?

Comment: I have set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in the Azure portal directly, under Configuration > App Settings.

Comment: sorry, i’ve missread your question. this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161103/how-to-generate-the-appsettings-environmentname-json-file

Comment: also, using default web builder should be enough since it applies correct appsettings file based on environment set.